# Translating "each other's" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

I know there are several approximate ways to convey the sense of "each other" in Spanish, some of them being `entre ellos`, `uno al otro`, and even `mutuamente`. However, I am struggling to turn this expression into possessive. What is the best way to render a sentence like this into Spanish:

> Let's share each other's posts with our respective followers on
>   Twitter

Here's my attempt which is obviously wrong:

> Compartamos los artículos del uno al otro con nuestros respectivos
>   seguidores en Twitter.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can say

> Compartamos los artículos de cada uno/de los demás (...)

---

**post** also stands for **publicación** when it comes to social media.

Comment: +1 por corregir publicación en vez de artículo

Answer (score 3):

I believe each other has multiple translations. It all depends on the situation.

Play with each other = Jueguen juntos

In your case: Let's share each other's posts with our respective followers on Twitter

"Compartamos nuestras publicaciones uno con el otro y con nuestros seguidores en Twitter"

Comment: Good point about finding alternative phrasing instead of using the same phrase in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are trying to do is to use the possesive for each other, is that right?

This will be correct:

> Compartamos nuestros artículos mutuamente...

Using the nuestros possesive and mutuamente you are also expressing the same thing, but what you've said previously it's also correct. 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a case where English uses "each other's" but Spanish phrases it differently.

Galatas 6:2

Sobrellevad los unos las cargas de los otros, y cumplid así la ley de Cristo.

Many English translations use "each other's burdens".  Admittedly, this is not a case of translating English into Spanish.  Both the English texts and the Spanish one are translations from Greek.

Answer (score 2):

Una traducción muy literal y algo recargada pero correcta sería:

> Vamos mutuamente a compartir nuestros mensajes con nuestros
>   respectivos seguidores.

o más simplemente:

> Compartamos los mensajes del otro con nuestros respectivos seguidores.

Si se quiere reforzar el hecho de ser una acción mútua, puede añadirse "ambos" o "los dos":

> Vamos ambos a compartir los mensajes del otro con nuestros respectivos
>   seguidores.
>
> Los dos vamos a compartir los mensajes del otro con nuestros
>   respectivos seguidores.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best option, for your case:

> Compartamos los posts de los demás con nuestros seguidores en Twiter

Comment: No es correcto, "de los demás" se interpreta como de "todos los otros",

Answer (score 1):

In this case I wouldn't go for the direct translation; a spanish man / woman (I'm spanish) would say something like:

> Compartamos nuestros posts recíprocamente con los followers del otro en
>   Twitter.

Or... simpler, rethinking the whole thing:

> Compartamos mis posts con tus followers y tus posts con los míos en
>   Twitter.